# Как закрыть родительское окно из дочернего?

Tags: winforms, c++

Здравствуйте!

Такая проблема: есть родительское окно Form1, есть дочернее Form2; При запуске приложения запускается окно Form1, оно создает окно Form2... В Form2 нужно ввести пароль, логин, и т.п. Если пользователь нажал на Х, то нужно закрыть оба окна и остановить программу... Вопрос, как это сделать? Написал такую штуку в форм2:

```
void Form2::Form2_FormClosing(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::FormClosingEventArgs^  e) {
    owner->label2->Text="fghfhf";
    //Close();// на этом происходит зависание...
    //owner->Close();//и на этом тоже
         }
Похоже, вызывается обработчик кучу раз, зацикливается... Может я не прав? Что происходит? Как можно это организовать?
```

Comment: Попробуйте не на Closing, а на Closed. На Closing по идее и должно зациклиться, вы ж не проверяете рекурсивный вызов.

---
А всё же, почему C++/CLI а не C#?

Comment: Может быть лучше сначала предложить ввести логин/пароль в Form2, и, если пользователь правильно ввел пароль, то выводить Form1? Обычный порядок аутентификации...

Comment: Дочернее окно не должно закрывать родительское хотя бы потому, что это плохой дизайн.

Comment: "Дочернее окно не должно закрывать родительское хотя бы потому, что это плохой дизайн." Ну а если нужно именно так...

Comment: "Может быть лучше сначала предложить ввести логин/пароль в Form2, и, если пользователь правильно ввел пароль, то выводить Form1? Обычный порядок аутентификации..." Именно так и делаю же.

Comment: Что-то не работает... Дочернее на Closed не подвисает... Закрывается.. А родительское подвисает. Сделал пока так: в родительском и дочернем создал по обработчику закрытия ...Closed. Закрываю дочернее окно, всё ок, затем крестиком закрываю родительское, захожу в обработчик закрытия родительского, затем перебрасывает в обработчик закрытия дочернего, затем перебрасывает в обработчик родительского ииии зацикливаюсь на Close() в родительском... Стрелка с него даже не сходит...

Comment: Тебе обязательно делать в C++?я заню как сделать это быстро через конструктор программ hiasm.Если заинтересовало мой скайп:kravchenko19751205.

Comment: @Aller, нет, вы не так делаете, вы описали ситуацию по другому в вопросе. Зачем вам промежуточное Form1, которое вызывает Form2?

Comment: @Alerr: если вы поменяли на Closed, приведите новый код, посмотрим.

Comment: @Alerr: ну, вам нужен call stack в момент зависания. Приостановите выполнение и посмотрите call stack.

Answer (score 1):

Пишу код после изменений в ответ т.к. в коментарии "не влезает". Form3...-это Form2

Form1.h

```
...
    public: System::Void Form1_FormClosed(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::FormClosedEventArgs^  e);
    };
    }
```

Form1.cpp

```
....
void Form1::Form1_FormClosed(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::FormClosedEventArgs^ e)
{Close();}
}
```

Form3.h

```
.....
private: System::Void Form3_FormClosed(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::FormClosedEventArgs^  e);

    };
}
```

Form3.cpp

```
...
void Form3::Form3_FormClosed(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::FormClosedEventArgs^  e) {
    owner->Close();
             }

}
```

Comment: @Alerr: не, вы делаете неправильно.

Событие `FormClosed` генерируется, когда форма уже на пути к закрытию, поэтому вызывать внутри `Close()` не имеет смысла. Что имеет смысл, это при закрытии `Form3` закрыть `Form1`, а этого вы как раз и не делаете.

Comment: @Alerr: может, вы всё ещё вызываете `Close()` в `Form1.FormClosed`?

Comment: да нет, там вообще ничего не делаю..

Comment: @Alerr: а в FormClosing?

Comment: @Alerr: Странно. Тогда посмотрите в отладчике, что именно зацикливается (call stack).

Comment: Зацикливается именно на Client_WFA.exe!Client_WFA::Form3::Form3_FormClosed(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::FormClosedEventArgs^ e) Line 69 C++

строка 69 это  owner->Close();
Стрелка после попадания на эту функцию с нее просто не сходит никак... Может нельзя закрывать родительское окно во время закрытия дочернего....

Comment: @Alerr, обновите свой код. Непонятно, где искать проблему.

Comment: Решил проблему, только по другому.. Окно2 сделал не дочерним... Всё заработало..